# Pass a value in PHP

Tags: php, html

I could not find anyone with the same problem, so I'm asking it out here.

Well, I've created a login-page in PHP and also a "Secret" page which will appear when you login. I also wanna display some information on the page (which is taken from the database) but somehow I cannot get information from the specific user. (It displays the information from all users)

So the page you can se below is from the "secret" page. also called as "hidden.php"

```
<table align="center" style="color: black; position: relative; top: 200px; width: 800px; line-height: 70px; border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5"><h2 style="text-align: center;">Dogwalk historik</h2></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Hund</th>
                <th>Vem</th>
                <th>Vad</th>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>Tid</th>
            </tr>
            <?php

                $serverName = "den1.mysql2.gear.host";
                $username = "HIDDEN";
                $password =  "HIDDEN";
                $db = "HIDDEN";

                include 'login.php';

                //Create connection
                $conn = mysqli_connect($serverName, $username, $password, $db);

                $sql = "SELECT Hund, Vem, Vad, Datum, Tid from tbl_rastad WHERE Username='".$User."'";
                $result = $conn-> query($sql);

                if($result-> num_rows > 0){
                    while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){
                        echo "<tr><td>". $row["Hund"] ."</td><td>". $row["Vem"] ."</td><td>". $row["Vad"] ."</td><td>". $row["Datum"] ."</td><td>". $row["Tid"] ."</td></tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "0 result";
                }
                $conn-> close();
            ?>
        </table>
```

And here is the code from "Login.php"

"userId" is from the html form, where I enter the login-details.

```
    <?php
session_start();

$serverName = "den1.mysql2.gear.host";
$username = "HIDDEN";
$password =  "HIDDEN";
$db = "HIDDEN";

//Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($serverName, $username, $password, $db);

if(isset($_POST['userId']))

$User=$_POST['userId'];
$Pass=$_POST['passId'];

$sql = "SELECT * from tbl_register WHERE Username= '".$User."' AND Password = '".$Pass."' limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){  
    $_SESSION['User'] = $User;
    header("location:hidden.php");
    exit();
}
else{
    echo "<label style='color:red;'>Användarnamnet eller lösenordet är fel!</label>";
    echo "<br>";
    exit();
}?>
```

So! I'm getting the error: Notice: Undefined variable: User

Comment: *if(isset($_POST['userId']))* should be followed by a **{** and the closing **}** should be at the bottom.

Comment: put those brace again. And echo $_POST['userId'] before that condition to check you really set that.

Comment: @unreleased I think I know the error.. Well, the ".$User." is not sending the value over to "hidden.php" by any dumb reason, do you know how to fix this? or atleast how I can make the "variable" public?

Answer (score 0):

this issue is very common, just put `<?php session_start() ?>` at the beginning of your hidden.php page.

As stated in the php help ([PHP Session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php))

> ```
> Note:
>
> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.
> ```

This is mandatory because session_start send the headers (including cookie information) to the browser, and if you fail to do this at the beginning, php will output a different header (without the cookie information) to the browser. Any attempts to send headers again are muted, and also if you force the send header will result in a "Headers already sent" error.

Regards

Comment: I also tried to add this 

`"if(isset($_POST['userId']))
{
$User=$_POST['userId'];
      
$sql = "SELECT Hund, Vem, Vad, Datum, Tid from tbl_rastad WHERE Username = '".$User."' ";"`

So, I'm not getting any errors, but no data is shown..

Comment: I think I know the error.. Well, the ".$User." is not sending the value over to "hidden.php" by any dumb reason, do you know how to fix this? or atleast how I can make the "variable" public?